# SQL Server 2000 Perforamance Question - Large Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, sqlperformance

Have a large table that is fast approaching 11 million records. (20 columns in the table).

My question is, is there a performance issue that I should be thinking about in terms of the Number of rows in a table?

Cheers

Comment: How is the table being used?? What kind of queries do you run against it? Are those well covered by indices?? Do you have lots of inserts, updates, deletes??

Comment: +1 @Marc_s - we need a lot more info about  your table and how it is used.

Comment: At 11 million records, probably not.  As long as you have proper indices for the most common queries, 11 million records is actually not all that big.

Comment: 11 million records is big enough that server and disk configuration matter.  If it's just plopped onto a single drive then all of the indexing in the world won't help.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the data in the table is used. 
Are there a lot of reads, a lot of writes?
Is the data stored and never updated, etc.

Without more info, the answer is "most likely"

Comment: Actually, the proper answer would be: "it depends" :-)

Comment: Table is well indexed, and only receieves updates during a nightly data sync.  During the work day there are a lot of reads from the table

Comment: @marc_s: I still think it's "most likely" rather than "it depends" ;-) Tables of that size where you don't need to think about performance are rare

Answer (score 0):

depends on your primary key and how u use it.
if most of the time, data is accessed only by pk and pk is basic number type(integer) it will be usual fast.

but if u use where condition maybe u need to tune it up. performance tuning is based on how u query it.

here's my tips

- equal operator(=) provide best performance.
- or operator sometime slower performance. separate into 2 query and union it maybe faster.

select  * from tableA where a = 'aaa'
union
select * from tableA where a = 'bbb'

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented there's nothing particularly huge about 11 million records and usage is pretty important but what's probably more important is table growth.

If your growth is ~110K daily (or 1% daily) you'll be able to monitor performance comfortably before you'll have to start needing to address problems by upping execution timeout values, reworking queries or taking more drastic measures like upgrading hardware, SQL Version or database sharding.

However if you growth is significantly higher, e.g. ~1.1 Million records daily, than you'll need to start planning very soon, because its likely that you'll start encountering issues at an uncomfortable pace.